# bash ps comamnd returns error when it executed from string

Tags: linux, bash, ps

So, who can explain this behavior:

```
# rv=$(ps axu | grep logstash | grep -v grep)
# echo $rv
root 6190 8.5 5.9 2248344 242440 pts/0 Sl 16:30 2:09 /usr/bin/java -XX:+UseParNewGC -XX:+UseConcMarkSweepGC -Djava.awt.headless=true -XX:CMSInitiatingOccupancyFraction=75 -XX:+UseCMSInitiatingOccupancyOnly -Xmx500m -Xss2048k -Djffi.boot.library.path=/opt/logstash-1.5.4/vendor/jruby/lib/jni -XX:+UseParNewGC -XX:+UseConcMarkSweepGC -Djava.awt.headless=true -XX:CMSInitiatingOccupancyFraction=75 -XX:+UseCMSInitiatingOccupancyOnly -Xbootclasspath/a:/opt/logstash-1.5.4/vendor/jruby/lib/jruby.jar -classpath : -Djruby.home=/opt/logstash-1.5.4/vendor/jruby -Djruby.lib=/opt/logstash-1.5.4/vendor/jruby/lib -Djruby.script=jruby -Djruby.shell=/bin/sh org.jruby.Main --1.9 /opt/logstash-1.5.4/lib/bootstrap/environment.rb logstash/runner.rb agent -f /opt/logstash-1.5.4/config/logstash.conf
```

But:

```
# cmd="ps axu | grep logs | grep -v grep"
# rv=$($cmd)
error: garbage option

Usage:
 ps [options]

 Try 'ps --help <simple|list|output|threads|misc|all>'
  or 'ps --help <s|l|o|t|m|a>'
 for additional help text.

For more details see ps(1).
```

And there is no problem without pipes. The following variant works fine:

```
# cmd="ps axu"
# rv=$($cmd)
```

Why is there an error if I use a pipe with these commands and execute them as a string?

Comment: http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/050. bash doesn't re-interpret the command line fully after expanding variables. You can use eval or better yet just make a function instead of putting it in a variable.

Comment: I edited my answer to reflect the question better. You may want to take a look.

Answer (score 1):

This can be done using `eval`. Be warned that this essentially is just taking a bad programming practice and making it worse as `eval` can open a shell script up to be targeted for arbitrary code execution attacks. Specifically in the case that user arguments are getting evaluated, though filenames could possibly be used to trigger this as well. That being said:

```
cmd="ls -la | wc"
rv=$(eval $cmd)
echo "$rv"
```

A more popular and secure practice would be:

```
cmd1="ls -la"
cmd2="wc"

$cmd1 | $cmd2
```

Or better yet, one can use functions:

```
functiona()
{
    ls -la
}

functionb()
{
    wc
}

functiona | functionb
```